# It is a good practice to use JavaScript to render the whole page?

Tags: javascript, json

I searched for a while and found nothing related about it. I even tried asking on the UX section and they said it belongs more here, so there we go again:

I'm writing a page which employees can edit, add, delete or view products in stock. It depends (heavily) on JavaScript to render and animate some elements on the page, in order to accelerate the page loading process and improve user experience, since the server only sends pure JSON and then the browser JavaScript handles the JSON and then renders (builds) the whole page.

It looks beautifully and loads really fast, but it is considered to be a good programming practice? And when it's going to be a problem? Even Internet Explorer or mobile browsers (Chrome, ABP Browser) displays every page without problems. No hiccups or other things. But when I saw those 700+ JS lines, the question remains...

And in case anyone is curious what the page looks like, then here some pictures: (May be irrelevant, may be not)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rLI6.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d90n9.jpg

Comment: As long as it's working and the performance is good then I personally don't care how things are built.  However, the Javascript *must* be manageable.  Consider the next person that has to work with it, rather than just enjoying what you've done.  If you post an example of some code then you'll get a better answer, as the answer is more related to that than anything else.

Comment: Probably worth looking into accessibility, most users are not bothered how things are built but most users don't have any disabilities. Depending on the supporting software people with disabilities may use, an all JS site might be an issue. Not up to date on that myself but worth looking into before making a call.

Comment: it goes against the principle of a separation of concerns and if the user has javascript disabled then your site will be completely broken but at the same time React works in a similar way

Comment: 700+ lines of JS is nothing.  I've worked on large enterprise apps with 10000's lines of JS. modular structure, async loading of files, minification etc will all help performance

Comment: @andymccullough I use XML async loading too, so that I can display things in a "Material Thingy" way, without every time refreshing the page. But on older versions of IE it's looking worse and nothing is really working. Everyone in this business uses modern computers with latest chrome, so this isn't a problem, but I'm scratching my head if I should continue that way... Because of that, I asked here...

Comment: It's not good: It's wonderful! Except, as @GillesC said, for accessibility not only for disabled people but also for indexing robots or other automated processes whose any time would want to consume data from your site.

But, anyway, most raw html pages are also terrific in terms of accessibility so, even if you have such kind of audience, you have chance to implement solutions (such as static versions, etc...) for that cases.

Comment: ...E.x.: A simple layout can consist in serve by default a static version server side rendered with javascript cancelling page loading and redirecting to the dynamic version.

Comment: The question you need to ask yourself is: "can my user get any value at all from this page *without* javascript"? If yes, proceed to bad idea. If no, then GTG. Related: https://nolanlawson.com/2016/10/13/progressive-enhancement-isnt-dead-but-it-smells-funny/

Comment: Just build your site using any SPA framework if you like this architecture. Building it with vanilla javascript certainly not recommended unless its a really small site.

Comment: Also to the close voters, its *likely* that this question will draw a lot of unsubstantiated opinions, but an objective answer is *possible*.

Comment: @JaredSmith Your question made in your first comment is a bit unclear: `can my user get any value at all from this page without javascript?`. No, without javscript nothing works, literally nothing. Not even logging in, since it's not a form that's sending things to the server, instead it's ajax that made that. So shouldn't your question be opposite?

Comment: @Fusseldieb started to write a response comment but it turned in to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO**. If there is anything valuable about a site that can be served to a user without JavaScript, then you are **doing them a grave disservice** if you fail to do so. Your code may (read: *will*) have errors, the CDN could go down, they might even turn JS off for various reasons. And it is entirely possible to log a user in without any JavaScript (using forms), and it is entirely possible to fetch and serve content without JavaScript (using server-side HTTP requests and rendering). You have structured your app to *require* JS, but nothing about it seems to actually require JavaScript except data refreshes. Unless there's something about it you're not telling us.

Good practice it isn't. Defensible in this specific case? Probably.

Please also note that many assistive technologies are now JavaScript-aware, and google at least is also so even if this is not ideal from an SEO perspective all is not lost. This really boils down to a UX thing.

And I'm not taking a hard-line stance here. There are obvious counter-examples and existence-proofs of things that do require JavaScript: canvas games, text/image/etc editors, guitar tuners, google maps applications, etc. Most of the sites I build require JavaScript. And for an internal site, meant for your own employees only? Requiring JavaScript is probably *fine*. But be very, very hesitant to absolutely require it for anything public-facing.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with it in theory. This is how React applications generally work.

Is SEO important? If so, you'll want to consider an isomorphic application - which means you generate the HTML output on the server (using pretty much the same code you would use on the client) and send that to the browser.

However, if you're simply using JS to render HTML content without a library like React, I'd say that's not such a good idea. The popularity of React is it's use of a virtual dom. The first performance bottle neck in most web applications is rendering, or more specifically DOM thrashing. React does some clever stuff to minimise the amount of rendering the browser needs to do in order to update your page.

These days, if someone wanted to build a web app, I'd have a hard time thinking of a good reason not to use React with something like Redux.

Comment: Google can render javascript. ref: http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157

Answer (score 0):

I want to note a couple things:

1st Server side rendering vs client side. Javascript is really good at doing things locally .... but if you are trying to hide elements on load (just as an example) you might experience flashing or other weird quirks which is a bad user experience. Having a suitable init state is very important. On that same vain - if you have a colossal app all in javascript it could hinder the UX because of long load times.

2nd Maintainability. If you are componentalizing the different UI elements then making changes to the view will come naturally. This could be said for all software, but if you are manually writing out your components without a framework or client library (like angular or react) then it'll become a burden for you and the people you are working with.

Comment: Hiding I am doing initially with CSS, so flashing things aren't the problem. And yes, I'm building everything from scratch, I'm not sure if that's a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you've provided, it's fine (describing something as "Good practice" I always think implies that other solutions are not good, when that isn't the case).

Without picking your application apart to see how it has been engineered, there are *potentially* risks around

- Code version control
- separation of content and presentation
- access control

**Code Version Control**

Only passing JSON data back and forth means you get big wins in terms of perofmrnace. But have you planned for how you accomodate deploying a new version of the Javascript code to the clients? e.g. using HTML5 manifests, version information in transactions.

**Separation of content and presentation**

Are you sending serialized HTML, Javascript or CSS embedded in the JSON? This could lead to all sorts of complications and security issues.

**Access control**

What is the worst that could happen if your app were compromised? The usual guidance about securing web applications is built around the more conventional server-side HTTP request-response model with sessions. And one of the first things anyone writing secure we applications lears is that Javascript doesn't get access to the session cookie. Oauth2 is specifically written to address this kind of scenario.

Comment: I'm loading the 'base' page as HTML and CSS normally from the server, this meany, the topbar, the sidebar and all other things. The main content I'm building with Javascript (So that HTML code doesn't come duplicated all over again, potentially slowing the loading time).